# C# connect to remote server using Microsoft Terminal Services Active Client (RDP)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, console, console-application

I have a piece of code that should connect to the server. The code is as following:

```
var rdp = new MsRdpClient8NotSafeForScripting();
rdp.Server = "192.168.0.101"; //adress
rdp.Domain = "localdomain"; //domain
rdp.UserName = "test"; //login
rdp.AdvancedSettings8.ClearTextPassword = "123456";//password
try
{
    rdp.Connect();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
Console.WriteLine(rdp.Connected);
if (rdp.Connected != 0)
{
    rdp.Disconnect();
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

This is supposed to "connect" to my remote server via 3389 port so that I can be able to read a file from my desktop which is called: "min.txt"

So far I have tried specifying the login data of my server but I always just get output of "0" in the console's window, regardless of whether I specify correct or incorrect login data..

My questions here are:

- Why is it connecting even with wrong login data (ip, user + password)
- How can I, once I've been indeed successfully connected to the server, access the min.txt file on my remote server, which is located at desktop...

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Anyone guys ? =)

Comment: Have you considered using PowerShell remoting?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can try specifying the password like below:

```
MSTSClib.IMsTscNonScriptable secured = (MSTSClib.IMsTscNonScriptable)rdp.GetOcx();
secured.ClearTextPassword = “123456”;
```

For reference: MSDN link is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/termserv/imstscnonscriptable-interface)

Once connected, you can access the file like a shared network file via UNC.

Example:

```
System.IO.FileStream stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("\\servername\sharedname\path\somefile.txt");
```

Then need to ensure that permissions are in place to access the folder.

Comment: It says "Theres no GetOcx() method available"

Comment: Still same issue =(

Comment: @User987 do you happened to solve the issue here? i'm having the same thing as you, still not found the solution. care to share with me how you solve this? thanks

Comment: @User987, have you found the solution?

Comment: @HowardHee no i have not